# Generat SMIME cert

Tags: email, security, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, smime

Install SMIME cert

openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout $EMAIL.key -out $EMAIL.crt -days 1095
Generating a RSA private key

writing new private key to '.key'
req: Can't open ".key" for writing, Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Command Prompt as Administrator, then the error will not occur

[image: run cmd as administrator]